# A better code maintenance for identical subscription handling code [Angular/Rxjs]

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Suppose I have the follwing code:

```
this.myService.doSomething1.subscribe(SAME CODE FOR SUCCESS|ERROR|COMPLETE);
this.myService.doSomething2.subscribe(SAME CODE FOR SUCCESS|ERROR|COMPLETE);
this.myService.doSomething3.subscribe(SAME CODE FOR SUCCESS|ERROR|COMPLETE);
```

How can I write an easy to maintain code for those identical subscriptions, so I won't have to repeat the same code for three or more times?
To be clear, the repeated code is something as following:

```
(success: any) => {
    this.sucess= true;
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

and it's the same identical code for all the three scenarios, and I'm trying to avoid repeating it for three times. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You're doing these three calls just after each other in the same component? And you want `this.success` to become true as soon as one of them succeed?

Comment: These 3 calls are in the same component, but within different methods in this component (not one after the other). Yes, and I want this.success to become true as soon as one of them succeed @ShamPooSham

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple functions that you maintain centralized and pass them.

```js
const suc = (value:object) => { 
// do something
};

const err = (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
// handle error
}

const complete = () => {
// handle complete
}

this.myService.doSomething1.subscribe(suc,err,comlete);
this.myService.doSomething2.subscribe(suc,err,comlete);
this.myService.doSomething3.subscribe(suc,err,comlete);
```

if you want to go further and build a composit object and use the spread operator to only have a single variable:

```
const default_sub = [suc,err,complete]

this.myService.doSomething1.subscribe(...default_sub);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! @Luxusproblem

Comment: @DimaK Passing in `suc,err,complete` is going to be deprecated in future versions of RxJS. I would use @fridoo 's solution and define an Observer.

Comment: @MrkSef do you have a source for this information? Because that is really important

Comment: Hmmm, I keep hearing so from teammates, let me look. Best I can find is - [See this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4202) and [see this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4159): Actually, what I should say is that some variants of the parameterized subscriptions are being deprecated.

Comment: @MrkSef this might only relevant for null params. Easy solution:  `const noop = () => { // no noperation };` instead of null

Comment: I mean, fair enough. At that point, it seems easier to just pass in an object with the properties you're interested in defined but to each their own! `theBestWay.subscribe({ complete: () => console.log("No Empty Functions Needed!") });`

Answer (score 3):

You can define an Observer.

```ts
import { Observer, PartialObserver } from 'rxjs'; 

const observer: Observer<any> = { // or use PartialObserver
  next: (success: any) => {
    this.sucess = true;
  },
  error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err);
  },
  complete: () => {
    console.log('complete')
  }
}

this.myService.doSomething1.subscribe(observer);
this.myService.doSomething2.subscribe(observer);
this.myService.doSomething3.subscribe(observer);
```